# Heroku + node.js = Port is already in use?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have been struggling with heroku and node to put it togather, i tryied everything and get error after error, here is my code:

```
var http       = require('http');
var express    = require('express'),
    app        = module.exports.app = express();
var port       = process.env.PORT;
var server     = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(port,{origins: '*:*'});

module.exports = app;
```

After i deploy my app.js, i get an error **Port 3137 is already in use**. I am losing my mind here and not sure what to do with this. Hope you can help me with that, thanks.

Comment: Do you have a Procfile setup? If so it should read web: node start. You don't need a Procfile for trivial node web apps.

Comment: I am not sure what is a Procfile, i think i don't.

Comment: Do you setup enviroment variable PORT.
If true, you should remove it.

Comment: Heroku uses a file called a Procfile to describe the services that an app has. It normally includes a web   entry that controls the start-up command. It looks like the default behaviour for a missing Procfile is causing you trouble.

Comment: Thanks Chriseyre, i will read about it more but i found out why it didnt work, i feel so stupid, all i had to do is to change "scripts": {
    "start": "node bin/www" to "node app.js"
  }, in package.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at: https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/scotch.io/amp/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-app-to-heroku

You need a scripts: node server.js section in your package.json

Comment: Thanks, i did it and it worked :) i changed "scripts": { "start": "node bin/www" to "start":"node app.js" }

Answer (score 5):

Comment out the stuff related to ports in www file,

because you app already start server in your app.js file:

```
//var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
//app.set('port', port);

//server.listen(port);
```